# Setting LayoutParams programmatically not working

Tags: android, layout-inflater, layoutparams

I want Imageview width and height to match the whole screen. After using Layout Inflater to inflate view I am setting Layout params on the view.But the height of image is not covering the whole screen. Here is the code:

```
    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager, container, false);
    itemView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager_image);
  /*imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));*/
    imageView.setImageResource(mResources[position]);
    container.addView(itemView);
    return itemView;
```

Doing this my width is matching the screen size but height is not matching screen. The layout I am inflating has Linear layout (width,height - MATCH_PARENT) and its child Image view (width,height - MATCH_PARENT). I don't know what wrong I am doing here.

Comment: Have you checked whether the height of imageview is fitting the screen size and not the actual image?.

Try setting scaleType To FitXY on Image View?

Comment: @Dr.aNdRO yes, it worked with setting scaleType ..Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these line in your code

```
imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

or

```
imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);
```

Try this it may work

Answer (score 1):

```
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    //if in activity then use
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    //if in adapter then use
    context.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    //if in fragment then use
    getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
    int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```